# How to convert an array to a record using typescript?

Tags: typescript, apollo-client

I have an array of person. `Array<Person>`

```
export const peopleExample : Array<Person> = [
{
   name: 'Leo'
   age: 12
},
{
   name: 'Donna'
   age: 20
}
]
```

I wish to convert it to `MockedResponse<Record<string,any>[]`

```
export const generateMockPerson = () : MockedResponse<Record<string,any>[] => {
    return peopleExample.reduce((prev, next) => {
        let myRecord = {};
        let keys = "keys";
        myRecord[keys].add(next);
        return myRecord;
    }, [] as MockedResponse<Record<string, any>>[]);
};
```

Mocked Response is

```
export interface MockedResponse<TData = Record<string, any>> {
    request: GraphQLRequest;
    result?: FetchResult<TData> | ResultFunction<FetchResult<TData>>;
    error?: Error;
    delay?: number;
    newData?: ResultFunction<FetchResult>;
}
```

I have been trying to use reducers, but i'm not successful.
Would appreciate the help.

Comment: What's a `GraphQLRequest` or a `FetchResult`?  If this has dependencies, they should be listed in the tags.  If not, then you should remove or declare anything undeclared so your code is a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.

Comment: Its part of this https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

Comment: Okay I've tagged it with apollo-client and maybe someone who knows about that will help you.  If you can remove the dependency then you might get more people available to help.  Kind of seems like a pure TS question but the example code depends on a library.